# 404 when I curl a kubernetes tomcat service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubectl, minikube

Hello I am trying to deploy a simple tomcat service. Below are the details:

1.minikube version: v1.8.1

2.OS: mac

3.The **deployment.yaml** file (I am in the directory of the yaml file)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat:9.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

4.Commands used to deploy and expose the service

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml

kubectl expose deployment tomcat-deployment --type=NodePort

minikube service tomcat-deployment --url

curl [URL]
```

I get a 404 when I curl the URL. 
I am unsure if there's an issue with the deployment.yaml file or some minikube settings.

Comment: Hi @Nath, is the pod on running state? Also, it could be that there's a configuration issue, you can check the logs with `kubectl logs -f <pod-name>`.

Comment: Yes its in the running state

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat image comes with the default preinstalled apps (ROOT, manager...) inside webapps.dist folder, to avoid them to be loaded by default at container startup (https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/issues/183). You can for example simply rename webapps.dist to webapps and (via e.g. kubectl exec <pod_name> -- bash), and after apps are deployed, the 404 should no longer occur.

Answer (score 1):

Sara's answer above pointed me to the right direction. Copying the files works but this requires a restart of the tomcat service which reverts the changes. I had to use 'cp -r' on the deployment yaml as per below:

```html
spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist/manager/META-INF/context.xml
            name: tomcat-configmap
            subPath: context1
          - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml
            name: tomcat-configmap
            subPath: context2
            mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
            name: tomcat-configmap
            subPath: tomcat-users
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: [ "-c", "cp -r /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ && catalina.sh start; sleep inf" ]
      volumes:
        - name: tomcat-configmap
          configMap:
            name: tomcat-configmap
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `target-Port` which in your case would be `8080`.

All of this is nicely explained on [Set up Ingress on Minikube with the NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)

> 1. Create a Deployment using the following command:
>
> `kubectl run web --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0 --port=8080`
>
> - Output:
>
> `deployment.apps/web created`
>
> 2. Expose the Deployment:
>
> `kubectl expose deployment web --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort`
>
> - Output:
>
> `service/web exposed`
>
> 3. Verify the Service is created and is available on a node port:
>
> `kubectl get service web`
>
> - Output:
>
> ```
>    NAME      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
>    web       NodePort   10.104.133.249   <none>        8080:31637/TCP   12m
> ```
>
> 4. Visit the service via NodePort:
>
> `minikube service web --url`
>
> - Output:
>
> `http://172.17.0.15:31637`

If that does not help check the logs of the `tomcat` pod to see it started on port `8080`
Look for a line

> 09-Mar-2020 13:36:00.157 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

You can also check docker logs by first locating the docker container `docker ps` and fetching the logs from it with `docker logs <container-name>`

Comment: I defined the target port. I also see the line in the pod logs. 

But It still returns a 404 on curl and strangely, I see no container running on 'docker ps'

Comment: Instead of tomcat try deploying nginx or something else. If your minikube installation is not broken then it should work, if it doesn't that means problem is with minikube.